# C# - Display running time in winform textbox

Tags: c#, ms-word

How can I automatically display current time running or increment every second in my textbox when my form loads?

I tried

```
myTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

but only displays static time.

Comment: "`display running time`" ?

Comment: Add a timer to the form, set it to trigger every second, and use its event handler to update the display.

Comment: Thanks Richard for the response. I tried doing it but nothing displayed in my textbox. I tried putting `myTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();` inside `timer1_Tick` event handler.

Comment: Post all of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public partial class FormWithTimer : Form
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public FormWithTimer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // Everytime timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
        timer.Interval = 1000;              // Timer will tick evert second
        timer.Enabled = true;                       // Enable the timer
        timer.Start();                              // Start the timer
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now - Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime;
    }

}
```

However while debugging this may show the vshost process time.

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer,set the interval as 1 and make sure its enabled then on the timer's event put your code